# Не устанавливается библиотека psycopg2

Tags: python, pip

Система виндовс 11, питон 3.10

```
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psycopg2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Попробуйте psycopg2-binary
https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

Comment: Попробуйте установить psycopg на Python 3.11, у меня получилось его установить. Хотя в Release Notes указано, что последняя версия psycopg2 поддерживает версии Python 3.7 - 3.12